# How Can I Sign A Transaction Server-Side?

Tags: transactions, nodejs, private-key, signature, server-side

I have a server-side Node.js app that sends a transaction to an Ethereum smart contract like so:

```
const transaction = await contract.methods
    .method_name([params]).send({
      from: [wallet_address]
    });
```

I have my private key stored on the server but I don't know where to reference it and how to sign the transaction.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can! You will have to us the EthereumJS-tx package from NPM, you can get more information here: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx. It's as simple as:

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const privateKey = Buffer.from(
  'e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109',
  'hex',
)

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  value: '0x00',
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
}

// The second parameter is not necessary if these values are used
const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams, { chain: 'mainnet', hardfork: 'petersburg' })
tx.sign(privateKey)
const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to perform three steps to sign in and access any methods from a deployed contract :

1. Create transaction
2. Sign the transaction
3. Broadcast the transaction

```js
// library required 
var Web3 = require('web3');
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
var web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/....');

const PRIVATE_KEY_1 = '0x562ca01e26a9f5b7a91c24beeb.........'
const AccountAddress1 = '0x8099F7ddEef97E7f1867DCA9ac990E9568ae40fc'
const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY_1,'hex')

    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(AccountAddress1, (err, txCount) => {
    
     //create transaction obj
    
     const txObject = {
      nonce : web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      gasLimit : web3.utils.toHex(8000),
      gasPrice : web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
      to : contractAddress,
      data : data
    }
    
     //sign the transaction 
    
     const tx = new EthereumTx(txObject, { chain: 'ropsten' })
     tx.sign(privateKey1)
     const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
     const row = "0x" + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')
    
     // Broadcast the transaction
    
     web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(row, (err, txHash) => {
      console.log('txHash', txHash)
     })
    
    })
```